# 3rd party module/plugin for managing equipment rental/tracking

Tags: ee2, add-on, solspace-calendar, addons

I have a project that requires online equipment rental/tracking, including booking, availability calendars, etc.

I know there are options out there that are non EE-based such as FreshService (http://freshservice.com) or Booked (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpscheduleit/), but it would be nice to have something that can be just dropped into our EE install with minimal fuss. Could Solspace's Calendar fit the bill?

Does anyone have any plugin recommendations? I searched on devot:ee and nothing I found looked like a good fit. We are running the latest version of EE (2.8.1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A note to mention that **Solspace Calendar is not a booking/reservation add-on**. It's used to create calendars and events (i.e. "the schedule"), but there is no actual booking functionality. However, I believe users in the community have likely managed to use Freeform or Channel Form along with Calendar to hold the "reservation data" (eg. a selected date out of a series of events).

Comment: @Solspace - Thanks. I didn't think **Calendar** would be a standalone solution. Do you know of any online resources that outline how this combination can be used for online reservations?

Comment: This sounds like a custom module to me or a time to use a 3rd party service.